AWS dms task failing batch apply mode
An AWS dms task migrating data from aurora to redshift table with IDL and CDC. Both the tables have primary keys defined. The DMS batch apply is enabled, but when updates/deletes are happening, the bulk apply is failing and going into one by one mode. Have checked the awsdms_apply_exceptions table. It is empty and there are no blocking exceptions.
All the delete/update cdc changes are reflected in one by one mode after long time. Very high cdc latency

Does your table have large blob fields?
